# How to remove double scroll. WebView in ScrollViewer in xaml uwp

Tags: xaml, webview, uwp, scrollview

I try to create page in uwp. I want have  witch a few elements ,  and WebView. How to avoid double scroll (one on whole ScrollViewer and second on WebView)? I want have scroll only on ScrollViewer.

[image]

**My xaml code**

```
    <ScrollViewer>

            <StackPanel Name="NewsInformation" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="Auto">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <Image Source="{Binding Image,Converter={StaticResource ImageShow}}" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                    <!--<Canvas Canvas.ZIndex="1000" Grid.Row="0">-->
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Foreground="red" />-->
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="bottom" Background="#cc000000" Padding="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SneakPeak}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  MaxLines="2" FontSize="15" Foreground="#ffffff" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!--</Canvas>-->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 10, 10, 5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreationDate}" Foreground="#595959" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="7"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="|" Margin="5,0,5,0" Foreground="#595959" FontSize="7"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author.Name}" Foreground="#595959" FontSize="7"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author.Surname}" Foreground="#595959" Margin="3,0,0,0" FontSize="7"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10, 0, 10, 20">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontSize="10"/>-->
                        <WebView x:Name="newsContent" Height="400"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I want show all html from WebView and have one scroll on all page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done in XAML.
You can do it by modifying the HTML content itself. For example, you can remove vertical scrollbar by declaring the following body in your HTML page:

```
<body style="overflow-y: hidden">....</body>
```

You can also inject a script after the page is loaded in order to disable the scrollbars.

```
myWebView.NavigateToString("<html><body>my very long content</body></html>");
myWebView.LoadCompleted += async (s, args) => await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.body.style.overflowY='hidden'" });
```